# Program that convert html to image

Tags: linux, html-rendering

Is there a ready-to-use program, that I can run from my web application, to convert an HTML file to an image? Preferably using Webkit, or another mature browser engine?

I tried [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list), but it doesn't render backgrounds correctly (while wkhtmltopd works fine). Is there one that works?

Answer (score 25):

**Method A**

Using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

```
$ phantom rasterize.js http://www.google.com google.png
```

<sub>Download and unzip the [binary archive](https://phantomjs.org/download.html). `rasterize.js` is in the `example` directory.</sub>

**Method B**

Using [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#screenshots) (Tested on `MacOSX`, should work on other platforms)

```
$ alias chrome='/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'
$ chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot=google.png http://www.google.com
```

**Method C**

Using [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) (macOS only)

Comment: Better use 'sudo -u user'. And with subprocess.Popen use '--log', because it tries put log somewhere in project root.

Comment: Here is a direct link on the [`rasterize.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ariya/phantomjs/master/examples/rasterize.js).

Comment: On some systems, 'libqt4-webkit' is not available, so replace that with 'libqtwebkit4'.

Comment: This worked very well for me, but with the rename mentioned in Respectech's comment

Comment: phantomjs has been abandoned

Comment: If you are running Chromium on Ubuntu then Method B would be chromium --headless etc. Worth noting: it takes a screenshot, so it's not going to convert the entire html page, just what's visible. Add --window-size=3000,3000 or something similar to capture the entire html page

Answer (score 6):

simply use firefox

```
firefox --headless --screenshot google.com
```

or visit [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots)

Comment: Requires you to close other instances of firefox which is a negative. Still got my upvote.